# Как в предложении удалить слова имеющие символы «ma» и «ov»?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, символы

В предложении нужно удалить слова имеющие символы «ma» и «ob».

Вот то, что смог:

```
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[200];
    cout<<"Enter your text: ";
    cin.getline(s,200); int m_id, a_id;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s)+1; i++){
        if( s[i]=='m'){
            if(s [i+1] == 'a'){
                m_id = i; a_id=i+1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

дальше хотел найти с помощью цикла назад и вперед начало и конец слова, т.е. до пробела или последнего элемента массива '\0', но не получается...

Comment: разбери слова как vector<string> куда распихивать слова и то что между ними, потом заюзать std::remove_if

Comment: не проходил еще векторы и работу с ними :(

Comment: Тогда пришло время пройти! Это же базовые вещи C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Был использован такой прекрасный инструмент языка С++ `STL`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<std::string> getLexemesFromString(const std::string& text) {
    std::istringstream       stream_line(text);
    return std::vector<std::string>(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream_line),
                                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
}

std::vector<std::string> removeWordsWithPart(const std::vector<std::string>& lexemes, const std::string& part) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    std::copy_if(lexemes.begin(), lexemes.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [&part](const std::string& lexem){
        auto it = std::search(lexem.begin(), lexem.end(), part.begin(), part.end());
        return it == lexem.end();
    });

    return result;
}

void outputLexemes(const std::vector<std::string>& lexemes) {
    std::copy(lexemes.begin(), lexemes.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "maven oven jojo tekken";

    outputLexemes(removeWordsWithPart(removeWordsWithPart(getLexemesFromString(input), "ma"), "ov"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: прекрасно работает, можно ли получить ссылку или что-либо чтобы изучить все что тут написано? я не дошел еще до векторов (

Comment: Рекомендую вам пройти курс (правда он на английском) на https://cppinstitute.org/
Курс там бесплатный, по С++ (кажется, там есть два курса по С++ один для новичков, а второй для профи). Чтобы посмотреть информацию по `stl`, вам нужен курс на профи.
Так же можно посомтреть информацию на https://www.fluentcpp.com/.